# Getting no email if I am an automatically added reviewer

Tags: azure, azure-repos

In Azure DevOps Repos we are using branch protection and the "Include Automatically Code Reviewers" policy. As automatic reviewer we have created an Azure DevOps team to list all the possible reviewers.

If now a PR is created then this team is added automatically as a reviewer. But none of the people within that team get any notification that a review should be done.

Is that on purpose or just a wrong configuration or a bug?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up [Team Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/about-notifications?view=azure-devops#team-and-project-level-notifications) in your project using [Manage notifications for a team, group, or organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-team-group-global-organization-notifications?view=azure-devops) documentation page.